# What does $A=B$ topologically. For example : $SU(2)=S^3$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to understand what we mean when two ensemble are topologically the same ?

Does that mean that there is bijection from one to another **and** if two points are close in the first their bijective points are close in the second ?

I would like to have a non formal explanation before a formal one.

Comment: We call maps that preserve topological properties *homeomorphisms*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Topologically the same" means *homeomorphic*. And that means that there exists a continuous bijection $A\to B$ with continuous inverse. Loosely speaking, this means indeed that two points are "close" in $A$ if and only if they are "close" in $B$. However, to really speak of *close* you might want metric instead of mere topological spaces; and even then, $f\colon x\mapsto \frac1x$ is a homeomorphism between $A=(0,1]$ and $B=[1,\infty)$, but for any given $\epsilon>0$, you can find points in $A$ with $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ and $d(f(x),f(y))>10^{1000}$.

More precisely, being homeomorphic mean that  what constitutes an open set in $A$ is the same (via the bijection) as what constitutes an open set on $B$. Thus a topologists (who is only in the topology, the set of open sets in $A$ or $B$) cannot distinguish the two.